Need Help with Sequence Puzzles
During an online assessment I came across a task where I needed to continue sequences. These two still puzzle me!

4 2 3 6.5 16 44

Options: 137, 142, 129, 132, 133

2 2 3 4 5 8 8

Options: 14, 17, 16, 12, 13
Author(s) of these questions are unknown to me. The company was Optiver.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Can you please provide the website address of this online assessment?

It is an internal platform of a company I applied to, it is protected by login and password, so Idk how useful it is to provide the link.

Were these interview questions or something?

The first puzzle

 There is a multiplication which goes up .5 starting from .5 each term and an addition which goes up 1 starting from 0.

So we have

 4x0.5 then +0, 2x1 then +1, 3x1.5 then +2, 6.5x2 then +3, 16x2.5 then + 4, 44x3 then +5


 44x3 + 5 = 137


Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our attribution policy; that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism. (You must know this, right? You've been here a while.)





 There are two patterns in the sequence.


 One of its odd members and one of its even members.


 The odd members are consecutive Fibonacci numbers.


 The even members are consecutive powers of $2$.


 The next member is even.


 So it is the next power of $2$, that is $16$.


Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our attribution policy; that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.


A straightforward way to recognize an integer sequence is to look for it at the on-line encyclopedia of integer sequences. The search for your sequence yielded three answers,
but only one of them fits the options.


 This is the sequence A240011, whose members are the numbers of partitions of $n$, where the difference between the number of odd parts and the number of even parts is $2$.


 It provides the next term $13$.


Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our attribution policy; that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.
